# IIS Redirects and children folders / pages

Tags: redirect, ii6

Silly question that I can't seem to figure out.  In II6 I need to set a redirect on a parent folder (using the "redirect to an url" option) but have sub folders (or sub aspx pages) still point to the page in that site (the designated directory.

II6 seems to have no problem with setting a *different* redirect on the child folder/page, but if it's set to the designated directory it doesn't take: leaving and coming back to that node in IIS shows no change.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the redirect setting on the subdirectory to the pattern:

```
*;!
```

that will disable redirects on that dir.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/41c238b2-1188-488f-bf2d-464383b1bb08.mspx?mfr=true